# flutter firebase_admob 0.8.0+3 iOS build FAILED, android works fine

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, admob

Just couldn't build iOS anymore after installing firebase_admob 0.8.0+3

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XS Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done. 5.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
2019-02-27 02:31:49.234 xcodebuild[78364:500868] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID D7881182-AD00-4C36-A94D-F45FC9B0CF85 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/VVDocumenter-Xcode.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
=== BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled, and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting to "Default" for the "Runner" target.
=== BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequest", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in firebase_admob(FLTRequestFactory.o)
"_GULLogBasic", referenced from:
_FIRLogBasic in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
"_GULResetLogger", referenced from:
_FIRResetLogger in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
"_GULSetLoggerLevel", referenced from:
_FIRSetLoggerLevel in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADMobileAds", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in firebase_admob(FLTMobileAd.o)
"_GULLoggerRegisterVersion", referenced from:
___FIRLoggerInitializeASL_block_invoke in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADExtras", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in firebase_admob(FLTRequestFactory.o)
"_GULLoggerInitializeASL", referenced from:
___FIRLoggerInitializeASL_block_invoke in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
"_GULLoggerEnableSTDERR", referenced from:
___FIRLoggerInitializeASL_block_invoke in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADInterstitial", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in firebase_admob(FLTMobileAd.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in firebase_admob(FLTMobileAd.o)
"_GADAdSizeFromCGSize", referenced from:
-[FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin callLoadBannerAdWithId:channel:call:result:] in firebase_admob(FirebaseAdMobPlugin.o)
"_GULLoggerForceDebug", referenced from:
___FIRLoggerInitializeASL_block_invoke in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
"_kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape", referenced from:
-[FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin callLoadBannerAdWithId:channel:call:result:] in firebase_admob(FirebaseAdMobPlugin.o)
"_GULIsLoggableLevel", referenced from:
_FIRIsLoggableLevel in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
"_kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait", referenced from:
-[FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin callLoadBannerAdWithId:channel:call:result:] in firebase_admob(FirebaseAdMobPlugin.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRewardBasedVideoAd", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in firebase_admob(FLTRewardedVideoAdWrapper.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone XS Max.

[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.2.3-pre.50, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 18D109, locale
en-HK)
• Flutter version 1.2.3-pre.50 at /Users/leungsiuhang/documents/flutter
• Framework revision [f460dd6](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/f460dd60df29f2b478bec4cc66db18b347d4cee5) (5 hours ago), 2019-02-26 08:08:28 -0500
• Engine revision 9f95ef23aa
• Dart version 2.2.0 (build 2.2.0-dev.2.1 f7e435ac26)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
• Android SDK at /Users/Library/Android/sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling
support)
• Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
✗ Android license status unknown.
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit
https://flutter.io/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 10.1, Build version 10B61
• ios-deploy 1.9.4
• CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin version 33.1.1
• Dart plugin version 182.5215
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 •
android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
• iPhone XS Max
• iOS 12.1 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.